# jqGrid 's checkbox control can't be chosen

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid ,if multiselect: true then there will be some the checkbox control.I used the jQuery Selector to choose these checkbox but failed.

My coders are：
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"][name^="jqg"][checked]').each(function(){...});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the code which you use is correct. I would rewrite it better as

```
jQuery('input:checkbox[name^="jqg"]:checked').each(function(){...});
```

because 'checked' must be not attribute, just a property. It's of course important that you use the code *after* the grid is filled and some rows are selected.

More better way would be to get the array of rowids of selected rows with respect of `getGridParam` method:

```
var selRowIds = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

Then you can get the checkbox of any from the items of selRowIds array by id. If the gridid is "list" for example and the id of selected row is "2" then the id of the corresponding checkbox is "jqg_list_2" (`"jqg_" + gridid + "_" + rowid`). In the way you can select every checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

Add code `event.stopPropagation()` will resolve this issue. 
Ex `jQuery('xxxx').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation();});`